# conventions for code in bin/www vs app.js

Tags: node.js

I auto-generated a Node + Express project. It created a nice project layout with `bin`, `routes/`, `views/`, etc., and it runs fine when I launch `bin/www`.

But it seems to have somewhat arbitrarily put about half of the 'wiring up' into `app.js` and half into `bin/www`.

In particular, the "create a server and listen" bits are in `bin/www`. Now that I'd like to integrate socket.io (which needs access to the `server`), that means dumping more code awkwardly into `bin/www`.

Is it unreasonable to simply move the majority this code into `app.js`, and leave `bin/www` as a mere stub that requires `app.js`? I'm trying to discover the idiomatic way to organize code in Node, and unfortunately it seems to be somewhat ad-hoc.

Comment: It isn't unreasonable and, in fact, use of the bin directory isn't very common. For a simple app, like a small website or blog, it's easier to maintain one app.js file rather than multiple files. Check out Sails.js and Kraken.js to see how they approach structuring an express app.

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis - change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

*There is no idiomatic or commonly accepted way to structure an Express app.*

**Slightly longer answer:**

The boilerplate that's generated by Express includes the `bin/www` directory but isn't very common.  As such, I think it completely acceptable to refactor your app so that the layout is less complicated or is otherwise more suited to your needs.

As support for this, you can see that neither [kraken](http://krakenjs.com/) and [sails](http://sailsjs.org/) include `bin/www` in their project structure but instead use a main `app.js` or similar file to organize 'boot' functions.  (Granted, both Sails and Kraken do a ton of other stuff under the hood of their eponymous modules, but the general concepts hold.)

The [MEAN boilerplate](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) also uses a simple approach using a simple `server.js`.